# Como evitar Excepción al cerrar una venta emergente vacía ()

Tags: java, mvc, eclipse, jframe, joptionpane

Quiero evitar que salten errores al dar al botón de cancelar o cerrar la ventana sin que se haya introducido datos.

**ERROR**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because "this.vis.nombreGrupo" is null
at controlador.ControladorMenuInsertarGrupo.inser(ControladorMenuInsertarGrupo.java:28)
at controlador.ControladorMenuInsertarGrupo.<init>(ControladorMenuInsertarGrupo.java:24)
at controlador.ControladorMenuPrincipal.actionPerformed(ControladorMenuPrincipal.java:62)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6617)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6382)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2264)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4993)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2322)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4934)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4563)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4504)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2308)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

**VISTA**

```
    package vista;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import controlador.ControladorMenuPrincipal;

public class VistaInsertarGrupo extends JFrame {
    public String nombreGrupo;
    public int opcion;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */

    public VistaInsertarGrupo() {

        iniciarComponentes();

    }

    public void iniciarComponentes() {
        
        nombreGrupo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Grupo:", "Insertar Nuevo Grupo", 1);
    }

    public void mensajeVacio() {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellene los campos vacíos", "BBDD Alumno12", 2);
    }

    public void mensajeError() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR AL REGISTRAR", "BBDD Alumno12", 0);
    }

    public void mensajeGuardado() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registrado Correctamente", "BBDD Alumno12", -1);
    }

}
```

**CONTROLADOR**

```
package controlador;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import modelo.Alumno;
import modelo.ConsultasBBDD;
import vista.VistaInsertarGrupo;
import vista.VistaMenuInsertAl;

public class ControladorMenuInsertarGrupo {
    private Alumno al;
    private ConsultasBBDD consulBBDD;
    VistaInsertarGrupo vis;

    public ControladorMenuInsertarGrupo(Alumno al, ConsultasBBDD consulBBDD, VistaInsertarGrupo vis) {
        super();
        this.al = al;
        this.consulBBDD = consulBBDD;
        this.vis = vis;

        inser();
    }

    private void inser() {
        if (vis.nombreGrupo.equals("")) {
            vis.mensajeVacio();
            vis.iniciarComponentes();

        } else {
            al.setGrupo(vis.nombreGrupo.toLowerCase());
            if (consulBBDD.insertarGrupo(al)) {
                vis.mensajeGuardado();
            } else {
                vis.mensajeError();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

**DISEÑO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta con: `if( "".equals(vis.nombreGrupo) ){`. Aunque no me queda claro el propósito de `inser()` ni por qué lo llamas desde el constructor.

Comment: El método  inser() lo cree, ya que no sabía como hacer las validaciones de campos vacíos y validar el tipo de texto que se ingresaba. Por eso lo metí a la fuerza en el constructor.

Comment: @Sal He intentado lo que me has propuesto pero me sigue dando el mismo fallo

Comment: No suena bien que para cada campo uses un InputDialog que no tiene capacidad para validaciones, sólo puedes re-lanzarlo hasta que el resultado sea válido; mejor usa JTextField y haz las validaciones en el momento más apropiado.